# How to retrieve large profile picture in Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using this url to retrieve Facebook profile picture.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/"+ Id +"/picture?=large"
```

The thing is, its still small. Its not showing up large. How would I get the large image to show up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://graph.facebook.com/1222530914/picture?type=large

You need ?type=

it is listed in the facebook graph api under user

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture?type=large
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this as a regular API request using  the new API "[field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)" syntax.

Like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/____OBJECT_ID____?fields=picture.type(large)
```